# How to handle bias due to self-selection in one group

Tags: matching, selection-bias

I want to compare two or three social groups across a set of dependent variables, using data from a longitudinal survey.

The problem is that membership in one of the groups leads to a self-selection bias, with lower participation in the survey. I would still want to compare groups, which seems to suggest either some sort of matching or adding covariates (or auxiliary variables) to the analysis.

I believe propensity score matching is not a good solution.

My use of stats programs is limited to R, Stata, and Mplus. I would be able to do matching in R or Stata and subsequent do regression/SEM analysis in one of these programs or Mplus. Or I might use auxiliary variables in Mplus. Yet I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: This seems like a good starting point: https://file.scirp.org/pdf/OJEpi_2015070913284831.pdf